# Changing IP tables for Monero on Tails returns error

Tags: monerod, tor

When setting up Monero on Tails I get an error (`Bad argument 'DNS_PUBLIC=tcp'`) when following the instructions given on the Monero Github site to change the IP tables with the below command:

[Using Tor on Tails](https://github.com/monero-project/monero):

> TAILS ships with a very restrictive set of firewall rules. Therefore, you need to add a rule to allow this connection too, in addition to telling torsocks to allow inbound connections. Full example:
>
> ```
> sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 2 -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 -m tcp --dport 18081 -j ACCEPT
> DNS_PUBLIC=tcp torsocks ./monerod --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --no-igd --rpc-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 \
>     --data-dir /home/amnesia/Persistent/your/directory/to/the/blockchain
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a newline character between `ACCEPT` and `DNS_PUBLIC`.

The `iptables` rule addition is the command:

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 2 -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 -m tcp --dport 18081 -j ACCEPT
```

And the subsequent command:

```
DNS_PUBLIC=tcp torsocks ./monerod --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --no-igd --rpc-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 \
    --data-dir /home/amnesia/Persistent/your/directory/to/the/blockchain
```

Comment: When I follow the steps above I get the following errors (though the internet connection works):

ERROR torsocks [15419]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)
                                                              Connection refused to Tor Socks (in socks5_recv_connect_replay() at socks5.c:543)

Comment: Point 2 of [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/12013/7493)